# Randomly pairing users only in PHP - solution

Tags: php, mysql

So i wanna pairing users only in PHP:

First, get one avaliable user id //right now not random

```
mysql_query('SELECT id FROM users WHERE state="0" LIMIT 1'); //state 0 = user avaliable, 1 = talking/playing with someone
```

$available_id = stuffs to get id from query

And then update:

```
$result = mysql_query('UPDATE INTO users SET state="1" WHERE (id=$available_id OR id=$my_id) AND state="0"');
```

if `$result == false` then it mean that no one row has updated. So back to First step,
if `$result == true` then what? it can mean that my row has updated or available user, or both. I am confused how to done with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code

```
$first=mysql_query('select id from users where state =0 limit 1');

$available=mysql_fetch_row($first);
$available_id=$available['id'];

$result = mysql_query('UPDATE INTO users SET state="1" WHERE
(id=$available_id OR id=$my_id) AND state="0"');
```

Answer (score 4):

`mysql_query` returns `false` for error. You can check the count of updated rows using [mysql_affected_rows](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-affected-rows.php)

Comment: @Kamil Krzyszczuk remove into from your query

Comment: Good spot, but this doesn't address the main problem.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `mysql_num_rows();`
http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php and `mysql_affected_rows();` http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-affected-rows.php

your query seems wrong `$result = mysql_query('UPDATE INTO users SET state="1" WHERE (id=$available_id OR id=$my_id) AND state="0"');` remove `into`

Answer (score 0):

No,

It is like this

> INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, DROP, etc, mysql_query() returns TRUE on
>   success or FALSE on error.

if the mysql_query return FALSE means you query get failed and have syntactical error, if TRUE, that means the query ran successfully but that does not mean that the row is updated.

You can really check a row is updated or not with [mysql_affected_rows](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-affected-rows.php) after the successfully execution of UPDATE query

Answer (score 0):

```
$id = mysql_query('SELECT id FROM users WHERE state="0" LIMIT 1');
$uid = mysql_fetch_array($id);

$id2 = mysql_query('SELECT id FROM users WHERE status="0" AND `id`!='".$uid."' ORDER BY rand LIMIT 1');
$uid2 = mysql_fetch_array($id2);

mysql_query("UPDATE user SET `user`='1' WHERE `id` IN($uid,$uid2)");
```

and pair it in your pair table.